# How to determine if the ring compound has optical isomers?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry

The first column and fourth column of the table below says that the compound has the plane of symmetry and is not optically active. However, I noticed that each side has different arrangement of the H and Cl atoms. Does it still count as being symmetrical? [image]

Comment: When you say “each side” which molecule(s) are you referring to?

Comment: Is there a plane of symmetry, if the sides are not mutual mirror images ?

Comment: Are you concerned about the chlorine in the lower right in structure 1 not lying on the line? It is on the line. It is where it is so that you can see it in the structure.